# What are HTTPS endpoints in Amplify DataStore?

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, endpoint

I have AWS Amplify DataStore with GraphQL for my app's backend. Are the HTTPS endpoints needed to encrypt data in transit between my app and the servers? Or is this already enabled by default (and I don't need to encrypt with HTTPS again for transit)?